# Dynamic twig variable names

Tags: symfony, twig

Given an array of variables sent to a twig template, such as:

```
$form   = $this->createForm( new ServiceItemType()
                           , $entity
                           , array( 'attr'=>
                                     array(
                                          'em'    => $this->EM()
                                         ,'group' => true
                           ) ) );
```

I want to capture the variables for easy access in twig.  However:

```
{% for key, value in form.vars.attr %}
    {% set key = value %}
{% endfor %}
```

remaps the key variable in the for loop.

twig objects to:

```
{% for key, value in form.vars.attr %}
    {% set {{key}} = value %}
{% endfor %}
```

And stack as I am aware never seems to address set.  Would anyone who knows, please indicate how to accomplish this variable assignment?

Comment: What about `{% set a = form.vars.attr %}`? then you could try calling `{{ a.em }}` or `{{ a.group }}`. Does it work?

Comment: that will work, but it is more of a work-around.  May be my best option.

Comment: There's probably not a native solution in Twig, but writing an extension that would allow for this functionality is certainly possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this syntax works

```
{% render "..." with {(key): value} %}
```

Did you try the following syntax? **As of March, Friday 22nd this syntax didn't work so you need to use a work around.**

```
{% set (key) = value %}
```

An alternative to that would be to include a template and pass and `form.vars.attr`.

```
{% include "YourAwesomeBundle:Controller:template.html.twig" with form.vars.attr %}
```

You can also merge `form.vars.attr` with another array using the [merge function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html).

```
{% set vars = {} %}
{% set vars = vars|merge(form.vars.attr) %}
{% include "YourAwesomeBundle:Controller:template.html.twig" with vars %}
```

Within the included template you will be able to use the variable `em` and `group`.

Comment: Twig Error: Only variables can be assigned to. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("name" expected)

Comment: Yeah, that means there isn't a way to do that.. It took me a while finding the `(varName)` syntax and while I was searching for it a Twig dev was saying that he didn't think this logic should be part of Twig. I gave an alternative in my answer if you are interested