# Twig - setting up a hash with indirectly named keys

Tags: hash, twig, key, names

I seem to have a small problem with setting up hashes inside a Twig. I want to use a hash object to prepare some data, for later sending it back through JSON response (in Symfony3).

With a simple example, my code is this:

```
{% set someName = 'Lola' %}
{% set hashObject = {someName : 'someValue'} %}
{{ dump(hash)  }}
```

I would like the `hashObject` to have a value of `{'Lola': 'someValue'}`, but instead, if I execute those 3 lines from above, I will get the `{'someName': 'someValue'}`.
So, Twig guesses that my variable is actually a string and uses it as a literal value (like in some ugly PHP-no-error-reporting nightmare :) ).

I'm guessing there has to be a neat way around it, but I can't seem to find it. Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic twig variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560280/dynamic-twig-variable-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for auto-spamming, but - as it often happens - I found an answer as soon as I asked someone. The solution is to use the parenthesis around the key name.

```
{% set someName = 'Lola' %}
{% set hashObject = {(someName): 'someValue'} %}
{{ dump(hash)  }}
```

It's actually a neat solution. Thanks, Twig team. :)